# TFS Scrum template - how to look at previous sprint's scrum board

Tags: tfs, scrum

I am on Sprint #2 using TFS scrum template.  I would like to go back and look at the Scrum board from Sprint #1.  Is there any way to do that?  If I go to the Board link from the main page I get to the current sprint's board, and don't see any links to go backwards.

Comment: Are you talking about the task board that resembles a Kanban board and tasks flow across the different metastates? Or, are you talking about the sprint details view that you would use to break down work and do capacity planning?

Comment: This currently cannot be done. Is there a particular reason why you would want to see a previous sprint's task board? All the tasks should be in the _Done_ state, therefore the board doesn't add extra value that a work item query would (or the sprint view on the `backlog` hub).

Comment: Sprint ends Friday.  Monday I come in to start the next sprint.  I want to look at the previous sprint board to carry over any tasks/stories that were not fully done in the previous sprint.  Yes, I know theoretically that all of the stories and tasks should be done, but theory and practice never seem to agree. :-)  The sprint board view would be the most convenient view for doing this.

Comment: Yup, I totally understand that (real world isn't utopia :). Could you instead use the Kanban board (available post update 1 for on-premise) to see which PBIs or Bugs are not in the done state?

Comment: Possibly.  But I don't want to invest the energy to switch templates mid-project.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way to do this either, but I've been using the "Backlog" area to view stories from any iteration, or the Work Items queries to pull up elements from a specific iteration.

I've been hoping for a way to see the board for future/past iterations as well, but there doesn't seem to be a way to navigate in that manner at the moment.

Comment: Yes I have been using the same workaround.  It is functional, but the sprint board view would be a bit easier.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but there is an "Unfinished Work" query that I use to specifically look for work to transition to the next iteration.  Seems to do the trick for me when using the "single board" view.

Comment: That might help.  Haven't noticed that query before.  I'll take a look thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In today's update of Team Foundation **Service** you are able to look at the board from previous sprints:

[image: The image shows the task board from a previous sprint]

Update:

This was a popular item in the user voice site: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2901542-ability-to-view-task-board-for-past-sprints

You can find the details of this change here: http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/home/news/2013/may-13/

Answer (score 0):

This was mentioned by MS here too: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2013-may-13-vso:

"you can now view a task board for past and future iterations, not just the current iteration (I can hear some of you cheering as you read this)."

Is it only "viewing" that is supported or can you in fact also "work" with the board and do changes? We need to do this to model our workflow and release management (parallel releases)?

We are still only on TFS 2012 here, and not sure when 2013 is going to be deployed.

Any ideas on this from you using TFS 2013?

Comment: I was fortunate to take the TFS 2013 for a test drive and can confirm that actually "working" with the sprints in parallel works fine.